# server1.listen(server2) как работает данная возможность?

Tags: node.js

Например:
var server = http.create server(handler);
server.listen(8080);
// Тут все ясно.

socket.io.lesten(server);

Сокет серер слушает сервер http. Как.это работает? Они просто слушают один порт и отделяют запросы кому какой? Или так нужно, потому что socket надстройка над http?

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/lib/index.js#L201